# Edge does not handle scaling and text-anchor:middle correctly in svg

Tags: d3.js, svg, microsoft-edge

I'm writing a graph display program using D3 and I found an issue in which Microsoft Edge does not handle edge scaling correctly. My code is below:

HTML:

```
<svg id="container" width="200" height="200">
  <g id="inner-container">

  </g>
</svg>
```

JS:

```
var container = d3.select("#container");
var innerContainer = container.select("g");
container.call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([.5,4]).on("zoom", function(){
  innerContainer.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ") scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}));

var nodes = innerContainer.append("g").selectAll(".graph-node");
var labels = innerContainer.append("g").selectAll(".graph-label");

var data = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

nodes.data(data).enter().call(function (selection){
  selection = selection.append("g");
  selection.attr("class", ".graph-node");
  selection.attr("transform", function(d, i){
    return ["translate(", (i * 20).toString(), " ", (i * 20).toString(), ")"].join("");
  });
  selection.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("rx", 2).attr("ry", 2)
    .attr("fill", "red");
  selection.append("text")
    .text(function(d){ return d; })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", 10).attr("y", 15)
    .style("fill", "white");
});
labels.data(data).enter().call(function (selection){
  selection = selection.append("g");
  selection.attr("class", "graph-label");
  selection.append("text")
    .text(function (d) { return "Node" + d; });
  selection.attr("transform", function (d, i) {
    return ["translate(", (i * 20 + 25).toString(), " ", (i * 20 + 15).toString(), ")"].join("");
  });
});
```

[View in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lrn82yt/6/)

In Google Chrome, IE, and Firefox, zooming works exactly as expected. However, when I run this code in Microsoft Edge, the text labels on top of the nodes will shift to the right as I zoom in, entirely disappearing when they leave the rectangle. The problem disappears when I don't set `text-anchor`, but that will mean that I have to account for text positioning manually, especially considering when the site is used internationally. (The text characters themselves don't matter, since they're from a custom font in the final product).

How can I work around this, providing a centered text label and yet having it still display correctly on Edge?

Answer (score 0):

Been in similar situations with browser incompatibilities in text layouting several times. If you fail to find the magic combination of CSS properties that works for all, here is one other option:

Add a `<pre>` element to your page. This element is invisible by definition. Select the element with D3's `select`. Add the text you want to layout as innerHTML. Use `classed` and `style` to style the element in the exact same way you will style the text. You can now get the text's exact length with the browser function getComputedTextLength or by reading the element's dimensions.

Hide all of this in a handy reuse function or TextLengthCalculator class.

Once you have the dimensions, you can calculate the desired offsets yourself and simply shift the text by adjusting its x and y attributes.

This is fast and takes localization and styling into account. It even is clean and reliable since it is still the browser itself that does the calculation. And although the browsers still sometimes produce different results here, at least each browser is consistent with its own calculation.